# How to split a string by multiple patterns in javascript?

Tags: javascript

input string: `"There are some strings in my question."`

patterns: `[ "Th", "er"]`

expected-output:

```
["Th","er", "e", " ", "are", " ", "some", " ", "strings", " ", "in", " ", "my", " ", "question", "."]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Sine you want space and punctuation marks to also act as seperators, add `\s+` and `[.,!?;]` to the list of given patterns.
- [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) the array with `|` and create a dynamic regex using [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).
- Add a capturing group wrapper `()` to preserve the separators when the string is [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the empty strings from the array

```js
const str = "There are some strings in my question.",
      patterns = ["Th", "er"];
      
patterns.push('\\s+', '[.,!?;]');

const regex = new RegExp(`(${patterns.join('|')})`, 'i')
const splits = str.split(regex).filter(a => a)

console.log(regex)
console.log(splits)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first split by one separator, then each item by another, and then flat:

```
arr.split("Th")
  .map(x => x.split("er"))
  .reduce((a, b) => [...a, ...b], []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split by the given pattern and by white space and include this into the result set.

```js
var string = "There are some strings in my question." ,
    result = string
        .split(/(th|er|\s+)/i)
        .filter(Boolean);

console.log(result);
```